# which is the best way to connect mysql database with android apps?

Tags: android

I am new in android.I have an online shopping project and i need to connect my android application with that database how can i connect with that database? Which is the efficient way to get the data from online database to my application?

Comment: btw, did you even try to search?

Comment: I believe that `the best way` will make opinion-based answers, which makes your question off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to expose your database directly to the internet. Instead, you should create a web-service that handles requests from your Android application, queries the database and returns results.